# VirusTotal service API always returns response code 1

Tags: php, validation, url

I am trying to scan URLs with [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/documentation/public-api/) service API but always receive `response_code = 1` even if URL don't exists:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [permalink] => https://www.virustotal.com/url/a92faaf82a911b2fe10ecbc51c6432f903b2a66d0686d6be0eeec78abf17cded/analysis/1348649385/
    [resource] => http://www.sdfjiodsffnsdklfjksdhf.com/
    [url] => http://www.sdfjiodsffnsdklfjksdhf.com/
    [response_code] => 1
    [scan_date] => 2012-09-26 08:49:45
    [scan_id] => a92faaf82a911b2fe10ecbc51c6432f903b2a66d0686d6be0eeec78abf17cded-1348649385
    [verbose_msg] => Scan request successfully queued, come back later for the report
)
```

But in [above manual](https://www.virustotal.com/documentation/public-api/) they write:

"response_code: if the item you searched for was not present in VirusTotal's dataset this result will be 0. If the requested item is still queued for analysis it will be -2. If the item was indeed present and it could be retrieved it will be 1. Any other case is detailed in the following sections."

**I am using [VirusTotalApiV2 class](http://www.ab-weblog.com/en/php-script-for-accessing-virustotal-api-version-2-0/) for that.**

Comment: Do you know `Recently VirusTotal updated its API to version 2.0. As the version 1.0 is now deprecated` and you need to update your class too ???

Comment: Yes, this class is recoded by author and updated to version 2 API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have received the answer from support:

> Hello,
>
> Perhaps the documentation is not clear enough.
>
> Whenever you send a URL for scanning, the URL might or might not be
>   scanned in that same moment, what you are doing is you are enqueuing
>   it for scanning. The response_code equal to one means that your
>   enqueuing was successful and the scan will be performed as soon as
>   possible (the API has a lower priority than the web interface).
>
> In order to retrieve the scan results you must come back at a later
>   time and ask for them using:
>
> https://www.virustotal.com/documentation/public-api/#getting-url-scans
>
> The ideal work flow would be as follows:
>
> 1) Check whether the URL was already scanned in the past using:
>
> https://www.virustotal.com/documentation/public-api/#getting-url-scans
>
> If it was indeed scanned and the scanning date is recent enough just
>   use the report you just retrieved, if not go to [2].
>
> 2) Ask for a scan using:
>
> https://www.virustotal.com/documentation/public-api/#scanning-urls
>
> 3) Wait for a while (couple of hours to be on the safe side) and ask
>   for the report on the URL:
>
> https://www.virustotal.com/documentation/private-api/#getting-url-scans
>
> If it still was not scanned just wait another while and poll the API
>   at a later time.
>
> Hope this is clear, please do not hesitate to contact us if you still
>   run into problems.
>
> Regards.